# Spring webclient - How to use a wrapper response POJO

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

We are trying to migrate our existing spring boot application to a webflux reactive application. Currently we make remote calls with rest template whose response is a wrapper class.

```
public class RemoteResponse {
    private String metatdata;
    private Response responsePayload;
}
```

Now with spring WebClient, the actual responsePayload will be a Mono. So ideally the wrapper may change like this.

```
public class RemoteResponse {
    private String metatdata;
    private Mono<Response> responsePayload;
}
```

Because of this I can't simply use this.

```
WebClient.create("http://localhost:8081").get()
                 .uri("/services/monoSamp")
                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .retrieve()
                 .bodyToMono(RemoteResponse.class);
```

I can't send the metadata in the response header as it may be huge.
What would be the correct approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: Where does `metatdata` come from? Presumably that's not in the payload?

Comment: `metadata` is some extra information added by the framework. Not part of the actual payload.

Comment: Ok, so assuming you have that metadata available outside of the web call, can you then just do something like `.bodyToMono(Response.class).map(r -> new RemoteResponse(metadata, r)`?

Comment: `metadata` also need to come from the remote server.

Comment: When I said it is not part of the actual payload, I meant it is some payload related information coming from the remote server along with the actual data(Response). That's why it is part of the RemoteResponse object.

Comment: This isn't making much sense to me at the moment. Can you post the current (non-reactive) code you're using to get the response currently?

Comment: I got the idea from your last comment. I just had to call `responsePayload.map(r -> new RemoteResponse(metadata, r)` and return `Mono<RemoteResponse>` from the server. This was a complete brain fade my side as I am new to reactive programming. Sorry for taking your time and thanks a lot for pointing me to the solution.